# Unable to access apache page on Linux Azure VM

Tags: linux, apache, azure

I've setup a linux VM in Azure. I've added incoming port access to the current listening port on Apache. I've also done a `curl localhost` on the VM and see the apache html text. I hit the public IP of the VM and get nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: network security group? did you allow a port on the NSG?

Comment: yes I allowed that port

Comment: firewall on the linux vm?

Comment: Have you check you subnet's security group settings?

Comment: Does it work now? which Linux are you use, ubuntu, centos or others?

Comment: ubuntu and no it's still not working

Comment: Please run this command to check apache listening on which port `netstat -ant`, and post the output here, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, please check those settings:
1. Please check Azure VM's **NSG settings**, make sure we have add port to inbound rules:[image]
2. Vnet-->subnet's **security group settings**:
[image]
3. Check which port apache listening on:
`netstat -ant`

```
root@ubuntu:~# netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.1.0.4:55870          191.237.32.134:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.1.0.4:55874          191.237.32.134:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.1.0.4:55876          191.237.32.134:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.1.0.4:55868          191.237.32.134:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.1.0.4:57772          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.1.0.4:57766          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0     36 10.1.0.4:22             167.220.255.8:53651     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

## By the way, **for test** please disable ufw with this command `ufw disable`, then try to access the public IP address.

**Update**:
I follow those steps to modify apache default port:
1.Modify `ports.conf`, change port 80 to 80:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2# vi ports.conf
Listen 90

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
```

2.Add `ServerName localhost` to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2# vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
# Global configuration
#
ServerName localhost
```

3.Modify default port in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2# vi /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:90>
```

4.Add inbound rule to Network Security Group:
[image]

By the way, to troubleshoot this issue, we can follow those steps:
1.Login this VM and use **curl** to test apache2:

```
curl localhost:90
```

2.Use your PC to **telnet** this VM's public IP and port 90

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 90
```

If you can't telnet this port, please check your NSG settings and subnet's security group settings.

Here is my result, it works for me:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2# netstat -ant | grep 90
tcp6       0      0 :::90                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Jason. Unfortunately, this still isn't working as I try. I changed my apache config and reloaded to listen on port 90. I also added inbound rules in the network interface on azure for port 90 to no avail

Comment: @ryan I have update my answer, please check it, to troubleshoot this issue, please follow those steps.

Comment: Jason, looks like everything was working. My company is blocking me accessing the IP from my local machine. Accessing via a different VM out of the company network seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that worked, important was to name the rule as apache2 !